# Search by a parameter on a database using spring

Tags: java, database, spring

I have this two id's, ID_A and ID_B.

What I want to do is to do a search based on this two id but the user doesnt need two input the two of them.

For example, I have two input boxes for the user to input ID_A and ID_B.

When searching the object with the ID_A, i want my query to ignore my ID_B (make it default-NOT NULL). On a database is possible to do that with the wild card '%' but I dont know how to do that in spring. Both of the ID's are BigDecimals.

I tried to do

```
if(ID_A==null)
substituteParmeter(ID_A)
```

The substitute parameter method changes the current value of a certain parameter to a wildcard '%'.However when doing this query:

```
Select t from Table t where t.ID_A like :id_a and t.ID_B like :id_b
```

If the id_a or id_b is '%', the program caught the error that found a '%' and its supposed to be a bigDecimal.

How can I go arround the error?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use is null  for the fields

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query like:

```
Select t from Table t where :id_a  is null or t.ID_A  like :id_a and  :id_b is null or t.ID_B like :id_b
```

Hope this is useful for you.